# Split data frame string column into multiple columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, r-faq

I'd like to take data of the form

```
before = data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2'))
  attr          type
1    1   foo_and_bar
2   30 foo_and_bar_2
3    4   foo_and_bar
4    6 foo_and_bar_2
```

and use `split()` on the column "`type`" from above to get something like this:

```
  attr type_1 type_2
1    1    foo    bar
2   30    foo  bar_2
3    4    foo    bar
4    6    foo  bar_2
```

I came up with something unbelievably complex involving some form of `apply` that worked, but I've since misplaced that. It seemed far too complicated to be the best way. I can use `strsplit` as below, but then unclear how to get that back into 2 columns in the data frame.

```
> strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_')
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] "foo"   "bar_2"

[[3]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[4]]
[1] "foo"   "bar_2"
```

Thanks for any pointers. I've not quite groked R lists just yet.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Use `stringr::str_split_fixed`

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(before$type, "_and_", 2)
```

Comment: this worked pretty fine for my problem today as well.. but it was adding a 'c' at the beginning of each row. Any idea why is that??? `left_right <- str_split_fixed(as.character(split_df),'\">',2)`

Comment: I would like to split with a pattern that has "...", when I apply that function, it returns nothing. What could be the problem. my type is something like "test...score"

Comment: @user3841581 - old query of yours I know, but this is covered in the documentation - `str_split_fixed("aaa...bbb", fixed("..."), 2)` works fine with `fixed()` to "Match a fixed string" in the `pattern=` argument. `.` means 'any character' in regex.

Comment: Thanks hadley, very convinient method, but there is one thing can be improved, if there is NA in the original column, after separation it will become sevaral empty string in result columns, which is unwanted, I want to keep the NA still NA after separation

Comment: Works well i.e. if the separator is missing ! i.e. if I have a vector    
 'a<-c("1N", "2N")' that I would like to separate in columns     '1,1, "N", "N"' I run     'str_split_fixed(s, "", 2)'. I am just not sure how to name my new columns in this approach,     'col1<-c(1,1)' and     'col2<-c("N", "N")'

Comment: This wasn't directly the question but you can use the following `|` to use several strings that you want to search for. For instance, for `_and_` and `_or_`, the code would be:

`str_split_fixed(before$type, c("_and_|_or_"), 2)`

Comment: @Martin That c() around the regex is unnecessary and confusing. It suggests the could be more than one pattern and I doubt that is the case.

Comment: I think the comment from @Martin above explains my issue. The char I needed to split my field on was a "|". The accepted answer didn't work for me until I added ```fixed("|")```

Answer (score 273):

You can use the `tidyr` package.

```
before <- data.frame(
  attr = c(1, 30 ,4 ,6 ), 
  type = c('foo_and_bar', 'foo_and_bar_2')
)

library(tidyr)
before |>
  separate_wider_delim(type, delim = "_and_", names = c("foo", "bar"))
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#    attr foo   bar  
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 foo   bar  
# 2    30 foo   bar_2
# 3     4 foo   bar  
# 4     6 foo   bar_2
```

(Or using older versions of `tidyr`)

```
before %>%
  separate(type, c("foo", "bar"), "_and_")

##   attr foo   bar
## 1    1 foo   bar
## 2   30 foo bar_2
## 3    4 foo   bar
## 4    6 foo bar_2
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit number of splits with separate? Let's say I want to split on '_' only once (or do it with `str_split_fixed` and adding columns to existing dataframe)?

Comment: @hadley How about if I want to split based on second `_`? I want the values as `foo_and`, `bar`/`bar_2`?

Comment: `tidyr::separate` has been superseded by `tidyr::separate_wider_delim`.

Answer (score 94):

5 years later adding the obligatory `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table) ## v 1.9.6+ 
setDT(before)[, paste0("type", 1:2) := tstrsplit(type, "_and_")]
before
#    attr          type type1 type2
# 1:    1   foo_and_bar   foo   bar
# 2:   30 foo_and_bar_2   foo bar_2
# 3:    4   foo_and_bar   foo   bar
# 4:    6 foo_and_bar_2   foo bar_2
```

We could also both make sure that the resulting columns will have correct types *and* improve performance by adding `type.convert` and `fixed` arguments (since `"_and_"` isn't really a regex)

```
setDT(before)[, paste0("type", 1:2) := tstrsplit(type, "_and_", type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)]
```

Comment: if the number of your `'_and_'` patterns vary, you can find out the maximum number of matches (i.e. future columns) with `max(lengths(strsplit(before$type, '_and_')))`

Comment: This is my favorite answer, works very well!
Could you please explain how it works. Why transpose(strsplit(…)) and isn't paste0 for concatenating strings - not splitting them...

Comment: @Gecko I'm not sure what is the question. If you just use `strsplit` it creates a single vector with 2 values in each slot, so `tstrsplit` transposes it into 2 vectors with a single value in each. `paste0` is just used in order to create the column names, it is not used on the values. On the LHS of the equation are the column names, on the RHS is the split + transpose operation on the column. `:=` stands for "*assign in place*", hence you don't see the `<-` assignment operator there.

Answer (score 77):

Yet another approach: use `rbind` on `out`:

```
before <- data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2'))  
out <- strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_') 
do.call(rbind, out)

     [,1]  [,2]   
[1,] "foo" "bar"  
[2,] "foo" "bar_2"
[3,] "foo" "bar"  
[4,] "foo" "bar_2"
```

And to combine:

```
data.frame(before$attr, do.call(rbind, out))
```

Comment: Another alternative on newer R versions is `strcapture("(.*)_and_(.*)", as.character(before$type), data.frame(type_1 = "", type_2 = ""))`

Comment: This is the correct solution. Simple and doesn't require thrid-party packages.

Answer (score 46):

Notice that sapply with "[" can be used to extract either the first or second items in those lists so:

```
before$type_1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_'), "[", 1)
before$type_2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_'), "[", 2)
before$type <- NULL
```

And here's a gsub method:

```
before$type_1 <- gsub("_and_.+$", "", before$type)
before$type_2 <- gsub("^.+_and_", "", before$type)
before$type <- NULL
```

Answer (score 36):

here is a one liner along the same lines as aniko's solution, but using hadley's stringr package:

```
do.call(rbind, str_split(before$type, '_and_'))
```

Comment: Good catch, best solution for me. Though a bit slower than with the `stringr` package.

Comment: did this function get renamed to `strsplit()` ?

Answer (score 31):

To add to the options, you could also use my `splitstackshape::cSplit` function like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(before, "type", "_and_")
#    attr type_1 type_2
# 1:    1    foo    bar
# 2:   30    foo  bar_2
# 3:    4    foo    bar
# 4:    6    foo  bar_2
```

Comment: 3 years later - this option is working best for a similar problem I have - however the dataframe I am working with has 54 columns and I need to split all of them into two. Is there a way to do this using this method - short of typing out the above command 54 times? Many thanks, Nicki.

Comment: @Nicki, Have you tried providing a vector of the column names or the column positions? That should do it....

Comment: It wasnt just renaming the columns - I needed to literally split the columns as above effectively doubling the number of columns in my df. The below was what I used in the end: df2 <- cSplit(df1, splitCols = 1:54, "/")

Answer (score 30):

The subject is *almost* exhausted, I 'd like though to offer a solution to a slightly more general version where you don't know the number of output columns, a priori. So for example you have

```
before = data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2', 'foo_and_bar_2_and_bar_3', 'foo_and_bar'))
  attr                    type
1    1             foo_and_bar
2   30           foo_and_bar_2
3    4 foo_and_bar_2_and_bar_3
4    6             foo_and_bar
```

We can't use dplyr `separate()` because we don't know the number of the result columns before the split, so I have then created a function that uses `stringr` to split a column, given the pattern and a name prefix for the generated columns. I hope the coding patterns used, are correct.

```
split_into_multiple <- function(column, pattern = ", ", into_prefix){
  cols <- str_split_fixed(column, pattern, n = Inf)
  # Sub out the ""'s returned by filling the matrix to the right, with NAs which are useful
  cols[which(cols == "")] <- NA
  cols <- as.tibble(cols)
  # name the 'cols' tibble as 'into_prefix_1', 'into_prefix_2', ..., 'into_prefix_m' 
  # where m = # columns of 'cols'
  m <- dim(cols)[2]

  names(cols) <- paste(into_prefix, 1:m, sep = "_")
  return(cols)
}
```

We can then use `split_into_multiple` in a dplyr pipe as follows:

```
after <- before %>% 
  bind_cols(split_into_multiple(.$type, "_and_", "type")) %>% 
  # selecting those that start with 'type_' will remove the original 'type' column
  select(attr, starts_with("type_"))

>after
  attr type_1 type_2 type_3
1    1    foo    bar   <NA>
2   30    foo  bar_2   <NA>
3    4    foo  bar_2  bar_3
4    6    foo    bar   <NA>
```

And then we can use `gather` to tidy up...

```
after %>% 
  gather(key, val, -attr, na.rm = T)

   attr    key   val
1     1 type_1   foo
2    30 type_1   foo
3     4 type_1   foo
4     6 type_1   foo
5     1 type_2   bar
6    30 type_2 bar_2
7     4 type_2 bar_2
8     6 type_2   bar
11    4 type_3 bar_3
```

Comment: This is very useful. Years later, I am wondering if it is possible to introduce colnames that can be inserted in a for loop.
For example, I want to split_into_multiple  10 columns (or more) and I don't want to split them each column at a time. I want the resulting split columns to bind together. I can't find the way to programatically select the column names (it gives me error) the option !!as.name() says there's not such attribute... 
How would you do it?

Comment: I am glad you still find it useful @MEC. My R knowledge has abandoned me and don't know how to hint you with this part. I think Python `pandas` might offer something but needs some homework...

Answer (score 18):

An easy way is to use `sapply()` and the `[` function:

```
before <- data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2'))
out <- strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_')
```

For example:

```
> data.frame(t(sapply(out, `[`)))
   X1    X2
1 foo   bar
2 foo bar_2
3 foo   bar
4 foo bar_2
```

`sapply()`'s result is a matrix and needs transposing and casting back to a data frame. It is then some simple manipulations that yield the result you wanted:

```
after <- with(before, data.frame(attr = attr))
after <- cbind(after, data.frame(t(sapply(out, `[`))))
names(after)[2:3] <- paste("type", 1:2, sep = "_")
```

At this point, `after` is what you wanted

```
> after
  attr type_1 type_2
1    1    foo    bar
2   30    foo  bar_2
3    4    foo    bar
4    6    foo  bar_2
```

Answer (score 11):

Since R version 3.4.0 you can use `strcapture()` from the *utils* package (included with base R installs), binding the output onto the other column(s).

```
out <- strcapture(
    "(.*)_and_(.*)",
    as.character(before$type),
    data.frame(type_1 = character(), type_2 = character())
)

cbind(before["attr"], out)
#   attr type_1 type_2
# 1    1    foo    bar
# 2   30    foo  bar_2
# 3    4    foo    bar
# 4    6    foo  bar_2
```

Comment: This is the most coherent 'built for purpose'.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a base R one liner that overlaps a number of previous solutions, but returns a data.frame with the proper names.

```
out <- setNames(data.frame(before$attr,
                  do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(before$type),
                                          split="_and_"))),
                  c("attr", paste0("type_", 1:2)))
out
  attr type_1 type_2
1    1    foo    bar
2   30    foo  bar_2
3    4    foo    bar
4    6    foo  bar_2
```

It uses `strsplit` to break up the variable, and `data.frame` with `do.call`/`rbind` to put the data back into a data.frame. The additional  incremental improvement is the use of `setNames` to add variable names to the data.frame.

Answer (score 8):

This question is pretty old but I'll add the solution I found the be the simplest at present.

```
library(reshape2)
before = data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2'))
newColNames <- c("type1", "type2")
newCols <- colsplit(before$type, "_and_", newColNames)
after <- cbind(before, newCols)
after$type <- NULL
after
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest when it comes to managing df vectors

Answer (score 7):

base but probably slow:

```
n <- 1
for(i in strsplit(as.character(before$type),'_and_')){
     before[n, 'type_1'] <- i[[1]]
     before[n, 'type_2'] <- i[[2]]
     n <- n + 1
}

##   attr          type type_1 type_2
## 1    1   foo_and_bar    foo    bar
## 2   30 foo_and_bar_2    foo  bar_2
## 3    4   foo_and_bar    foo    bar
## 4    6 foo_and_bar_2    foo  bar_2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach if you want to stick with `strsplit()` is to use the `unlist()` command. Here's a solution along those lines.

```
tmp <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(as.character(before$type), '_and_')), ncol=2,
   byrow=TRUE)
after <- cbind(before$attr, as.data.frame(tmp))
names(after) <- c("attr", "type_1", "type_2")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was asked `separate` has been superseded by [`separate_longer_*`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html) and [`separate_wider_*`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html) functions.

The way to do it now is:

```
library(tidyr)
separate_wider_delim(before, type, delim = "_and_", names_sep = "_")
```

You could also use `separate_wider_regex`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution. We can use `read.table` but since it accepts only one-byte `sep` argument and here we have multi-byte separator we can use `gsub` to replace the multibyte separator to any one-byte separator and use that as `sep` argument in `read.table`

```
cbind(before[1], read.table(text = gsub('_and_', '\t', before$type), 
                 sep = "\t", col.names = paste0("type_", 1:2)))

#  attr type_1 type_2
#1    1    foo    bar
#2   30    foo  bar_2
#3    4    foo    bar
#4    6    foo  bar_2
```

In this case, we can also make it shorter by replacing it with default `sep` argument so we don't have to mention it explicitly

```
cbind(before[1], read.table(text = gsub('_and_', ' ', before$type), 
                 col.names = paste0("type_", 1:2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, another tidyverse solution is still missing - you can also use `tidyr::extract`, with a regex.

```r
library(tidyr)
before <- data.frame(attr = c(1, 30, 4, 6), type = c("foo_and_bar", "foo_and_bar_2"))

## regex - getting all characters except an underscore till the first underscore, 
## inspired by Akrun https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752920/7941188 

extract(before, col = type, into = paste0("type", 1:2), regex = "(^[^_]*)_(.*)")
#>   attr type1     type2
#> 1    1   foo   and_bar
#> 2   30   foo and_bar_2
#> 3    4   foo   and_bar
#> 4    6   foo and_bar_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution that also is a general way to split a column in several columns is:

**Data**

```
before = data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4,6), type=c('foo_and_bar','foo_and_bar_2'))
```

**Procedure**

```
attach(before)
before$type2 <- gsub("(\\w*)_and_(\\w*)", "c('\\1', '\\2')", type)
#this recode the column type to c("blah", "blah") form

cbind(before,t(sapply(1:nrow(before), function(x) eval(parse(text=before$type2[x])))))
#this split the desired column into several ones named 1 2 3 and so on
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  attr          type             type2   1     2
1    1   foo_and_bar   c('foo', 'bar') foo   bar
2   30 foo_and_bar_2 c('foo', 'bar_2') foo bar_2
3    4   foo_and_bar   c('foo', 'bar') foo   bar
4    6 foo_and_bar_2 c('foo', 'bar_2') foo bar_2
```