# What exactly does sapply with '[' do?

Tags: r, string, split

I was browsing some answer concerning `strsplit` in R. Example text:

```
fileName <- c("hello.w-rp-al",
              "how.nez-r",
              "do.qs-sdz",
              "you.d-aerd",
              "do.dse-e")
```

I wanted to get the first element of the created list and thought I could use something such as

```
fileNameSplit <- strsplit(fileName, "[.]")
node_1 <- fileNameSplit[0]
node_2 <- fileNameSplit[1]
```

But that didn't work.

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350896/1150683) that suggests using `sapply` with `[`. This does work.

```
d <- data.frame(fileName)
fileNameSplit <- strsplit(d$fileName, "[.]")
d$node_1 <- sapply(fileNameSplit, "[", 1)
d$node_2 <- sapply(fileNameSplit, "[", 2)
```

However, I'm trying to figure out *why*. What exactly is happening, and what does `[` have to do with anything? It's semantically confusing in my opinion.

Comment: `[` is a function.  See `?"["` and the output from `get("[")`

Comment: Think of it in terms of subsetting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sapply` operates on lists, which are vectors where each element can take any form.

---

**In the special case of your `fileNameSplit` list**, we know that each element of the list is a character vector with two elements.

```
> fileNameSplit 
[[1]]
[1] "hello"   "w-rp-al"

[[2]]
[1] "how"   "nez-r"

[[3]]
[1] "do"     "qs-sdz"

[[4]]
[1] "you"    "d-aerd"

[[5]]
[1] "do"    "dse-e"
```

To extract the first element from each of these character vectors, we have to iterate over the list, which is what

```
sapply(fileNameSplit, `[`, 1)
```

does. It may be clearer when written as

```
sapply(fileNameSplit, function(x) x[1])
```

The documentation at `` ?`[` `` and `?sapply` explains why the shorter version works.

We use `1` because that is where indexing starts in R (unlike other languages that start at 0).

Answer (score 7):

R is very LisP-like. The symbol `[` is actually a function. When you write `mylist[1]`, what is actually happening "under the hood" is that the numbered or named items (only one in this instance) inside the flanking square brackets are extracted and passed to the `[` function from 'mylist` which became the first function argument, so it becomes:

```
 `[`(mylist, 1)   # that will also succeed if you type it at the command line
```

Both `sapply` and `lapply` have a trailing triple-dots argument. So the series of items being passed to `[` as it first arguments are just the values inside `fileNameSplit`'s sublists and the `1` is being recycled as a second argument, and you, therefore get the first item in each of those sublists. The `sapply` function creates a series of calls like:

```
 `[`(mylist[[1]], 1)   # as the first one with 2,3, ... in the [[.]] for succeeding calls
```

And then retruns them as a matrix or a list (depending on whether they are all the same length and the setting of the "simplify" argument.)

Because you used `sapply` with no "simplify" arg, the default TRUE gets used and the value gets passed to `simplify2array` and comes back to you as a vector-result, instead of the list that would have been returned had you just used `lapply`.