# Split an string by number of characters in a column of a data frame to create multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, text-processing

In `r` there is `data frame` (`df`) as below which has `ID` string of 10 characters.

```
df:
        ID         Var1 Var2
    1   0334KLM001  aa  xx
    2   1334HDM002  zvv rr
    3   2334WEM003  qetr qwe
    4   3334OKT004  ff  sdf
    5   4334WER005  ee  sdf
    6   5334BBC006  qly ssg
    7   6334QQQ007  kk  htj
    8   7334AAA008  uu  yjy
    9   8334CBU009  ww  wttt
    10  9334MLO010  aa  dg
```

**Intention:** 
Using `r` commands, I'd like to split the `ID` into two additional columns only by the **numbers of Characters**. For instance, I'd like to add two Columns (`Spl_1` & `Spl_2`) to `df` which the `Spl_1` has the *first four characters* of the `ID` column and the `Spl_2` has the rest of `ID` character (*i.e.* 5:10).

The expected `output` would be like this:

```
output:

    ID         Var1 Var2    Spl_1   Spl_2
1   0334KLM001  aa  xx       0334   KLM001
2   1334HDM002  zvv rr       1334   HDM002
3   2334WEM003  qetr qwe     2334   WEM003
4   3334OKT004  ff  sdf     3334    OKT004
5   4334WER005  ee  sdf     4334    WER005
6   5334BBC006  qly ssg     5334    BBC006
7   6334QQQ007  kk  htj     6334    QQQ007
8   7334AAA008  uu  yjy     7334    AAA008
9   8334CBU009  ww  wttt    8334    CBU009
10  9334MLO010  aa  dg      9334    MLO010
```

I read the following questions : [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns) & [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072281/r-split-a-column-to-multiple-columns-changing-pattern).Although very informative but still I did not get that how to split the sting by character numbers. I found the ‘[stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf)’ package, which I learn using `str_sub` command, I can split by number. see below:

```
 library(stringr)
ID <- "0334KLM001"
str_sub(ID, c(1,5), c(4,10))
[1] "0334"   "KLM001"
```

But I do not know how to combine with other  `r` command(s) to get `output` as provided above?

Comment: `df$spl_1 <- substr(df$ID, 1, 4); df$spl_2 <- substr(df$ID, 5, 10)` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Spl_2"), sep = 4, remove = FALSE)
#           ID Spl_1  Spl_2 Var1 Var2
#1  0334KLM001  0334 KLM001   aa   xx
#2  1334HDM002  1334 HDM002  zvv   rr
#3  2334WEM003  2334 WEM003 qetr  qwe
#4  3334OKT004  3334 OKT004   ff  sdf
#5  4334WER005  4334 WER005   ee  sdf
#6  5334BBC006  5334 BBC006  qly  ssg
#7  6334QQQ007  6334 QQQ007   kk  htj
#8  7334AAA008  7334 AAA008   uu  yjy
#9  8334CBU009  8334 CBU009   ww wttt
#10 9334MLO010  9334 MLO010   aa   dg
```

If we want 3 columns, we can pass a `vector` in `sep`

```
separate(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Spl_2", "Spl_3"), sep = c(4,8), remove = FALSE)
#           ID Spl_1 Spl_2 Spl_3 Var1 Var2
#1  0334KLM001  0334  KLM0    01   aa   xx
#2  1334HDM002  1334  HDM0    02  zvv   rr
#3  2334WEM003  2334  WEM0    03 qetr  qwe
#4  3334OKT004  3334  OKT0    04   ff  sdf
#5  4334WER005  4334  WER0    05   ee  sdf
#6  5334BBC006  5334  BBC0    06  qly  ssg
#7  6334QQQ007  6334  QQQ0    07   kk  htj
#8  7334AAA008  7334  AAA0    08   uu  yjy
#9  8334CBU009  8334  CBU0    09   ww wttt
#10 9334MLO010  9334  MLO0    10   aa   dg
```

---

If the numbers at the beginning are not of fixed length, use `extract`

```
extract(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Spl_2"), "^([0-9]+)(.*)", remove = FALSE)
```

and for 3 columns,

```
extract(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Spl_2", "Spl_3"), "(.{4})(.{4})(.*)", remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: For sake of my curiosity, what if I want three columns then. for example Spl_1 (1:4) , Spl_2 (5:8) , Spl_3 (9:10) . like for  0334KLM001 it would be 0334 , KLM0 , 01 ?

Comment: @Daniel You can use the `extract` i.e. `extract(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Sp1_2", "Sp1_3"), "(.{4})(.{4})(.*)")` or `separate(df, ID, into = c("Spl_1", "Spl_2", "Spl_3"), sep = c(4,8), remove = FALSE)`