# How to separate a column

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

The first column of my dataframe is a factor that contains two sets of information: the type of activation works (A1-4) and the month when it was carried out (about 50 observations in YYMM format). A simplified version could look like this:

```
A = data.frame(type.month=c("A1.1605", "A2.1605", "A1.1604", "A2.1604"), value=sample(1:4))

> A
  type.month value
1    A1.1605     2
2    A2.1605     4
3    A1.1604     1
4    A2.1604     3
```

I would like to get the `types` into one column and the `months` into another and I [read](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) that normally this could be done with the `reshape2` package when the variables are neatly separated (say e.g. the first half is only A1 and the second half is only A2). However, mine alternate (A1,A2,A1...) *and* contain two information (type and month). Is `reshape2` still a good tool in this case or I should think about something else?

My point is to keep the four type of activation works and months in one dataframe so that I do not have to store them in four different files.

Comment: You're going to want stringr.  Check this out!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns

Comment: Joy, thanks, I'll check it out!
@Frank, hope the title is better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This separates the string using `tidyr` function `separate`:

```
A = data.frame(type.month=c("A1.1605", "A2.1605", "A1.1604", "A2.1604"), value=sample(1:4))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
A %>% separate(type.month, c('type','month')) %>% arrange(type, desc(month))
```

gives

```
type  month      value
A1    1605       4
A1    1604       2
A2    1605       1
A2    1604       3
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Just wondering if there is any way to reorder the dataframe like this:

Comment: type month value
A1  1605     2
A1  1604     1
A2  1605     4
A2  1604     3

Comment: sorry, my above comment looks ugly. Basically I would like to order the df by type, not month. Is it possible to set that in `tidyr`?

Comment: found it: `Ord1=order(A$`, 
`A[Ord1,]` #I love this forum, thank you!

Comment: very elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drat, I forgot to mention regular expressions. You'll have to escape out the period like this:

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(A$type.month, "\\.", 2)
```