# Split a column based on a space between numbers

Tags: r, split

I'm trying to split a column in a dataset based on a `" "` rather than a `","` or some other delimiter. Is this possible?

so for example I have:

`VVV <- strsplit(df$col, " ")`

however I get the error: `Error in strsplit(df$col, " ") : non-character argument`
I'd like to separate based on the space right before the new set of characters begin. It doesn't help that a few rows have 2 spaces.

`aaaa bbbb`

`aaa  bbbb`

`caaa hhh`

What should I do instead?

Comment: You have a `factor` i'm guessing - try `strsplit(as.character(df$col), " ")`

Comment: And if you set `split = " +"` in your `strsplit` it will split on *one or more* spaces.

Comment: or `strsplit(as.character(df$col), split="\\s+")` if your spaces happen to be something other than a simple space character (e.g. - tabs etc)

Comment: @thelatemail the latest line made a new item under the "Values" header in the environment tab however it didn't split the tab in the dataframe itself. Was hoping to also be able to rename the new columns created by the split as well. If it isn't too much to ask.

Comment: @StargazingFish - you will have to assign the result back to your data.frame - potentially in parts. You may also want to look at the `separate()` function in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: And you can rename columns created by the split just like you would rename any other columns. I second the `separate` recommendation - it's very friendly - but you'll find it in the `tidyr` package not in `dplyr`.

Comment: How do I reassign the result back? And I've tried the separate that doesn't do it for me. And would like to focus on this method.

Comment: @StargazingFish - try this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4350905/496803

Comment: right well i have no idea how to relate that to what I was doing.

Comment: Use str_split from package "stringr". The function has option of Simplify = T which will give you output as a matrix which can easily rename.