# Extract parameters names in URL query

Tags: r, regex

I have a string in the format of an url query :

```
string <- "key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

And I would like to extract all the parameters names (`key1`, `key2`).

I thought about `strsplit` with a split matching everything between `=` and an optional `&`.

```
unlist(strsplit(string, "=.+&?"))
[1] "key1"
```

But I guess that this pattern matches from the first `=` to the end of the string including my optional `&` in the `.+`. I suspect this is because of the "greediness" of the regexp so I tried it to make lazy but I got a strange result.

```
> unlist(strsplit(string, "=.+?&?"))
[1] "key1"       "alue1&key2" "alue2"
```

Now I don't really understand what is happening here and I don't know how I can make it lazy when the last matching character is optional.

I know (and I think I also understand why) that it works if I excludes `&` from `.+` but I wish I could understand why the regexp above aren't working.

```
> unlist(strsplit(string, "=[^&]+&?"))
[1] "key1" "key2"
```

My actual option is to do it in 2 times with :

```
unlist(sapply(unlist(strsplit(string, "&")), strsplit, split = "=.*", USE.NAMES = FALSE))
```

What I'm doing wrong to achieve this in one regexp ? 
Thanks for any help.

I'm painfully learning regexp, so any other options would be also appreciated for my knowledge !

Comment: split's argument is supposed to describe a delimiter, not a format of the parts you wish to obtain

Comment: If you want to extract url parameters, you may want to have a look at the `urltools` package. It may have what you need. If your goal is to learn regexp instead, by all means keep learning

Comment: Relevant/Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns

Comment: `regmatches("key1=value1&key2=value2", gregexpr("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\\=.+&?)", "key1=value1&key2=value2", perl = TRUE))[[1]]` seems to work on your example string.

Comment: Although `shiny::parseQueryString("key1=value1&key2=value2")` seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: @nrussell I think this is worth adding as an answer.

Comment: Another option, `strsplit(string, '=|&')[[1]][c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose (url parsing) the best approach seems to be `shiny::parseQueryString` as @nrussell suggested

`shiny::parseQueryString("key1=value1&key2=value2")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first expression doesn't work because by default, quantifiers are greedy. That's why `.+` is going to match as much as possible. Why the `&?` is not matching anything will be explained in the next section.

**What's up with the second and more confusing expression?**

Let's take a look what you are doing.

> unlist(strsplit(string, "=.+?&?"))
>   [1] "key1"       "alue1&key2" "alue2"

You are splitting `=v` but why? Because you try to make it lazy, but what does that mean?

> ? Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match *as few
>   characters as possible*.

The least amount of character your regex matches are:

**=** (hard character)

**.+?** (one or more of any character)

fewest possible matches here is one character which results in `v`

**&?** (if this character exists then match it too)

since the previous expression only matches one character, the    character after `v` is not a `&` which causes this regex to fail