# Split dataframe based on one column in r, with a non-fixed width column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I have a problem that is an extension of a well-covered issue here on SE. I.e:

[Split a column of a data frame to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns)

My data has a column with a string format, comma-separated, but of no fixed length.

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), treatments = c("1,2,3", "2,3", "8,9,1,2,4"))
```

So I would like to have my dataframe eventually be in the proper tidy/long form of:

```
id    treatments
1     1
1     2
1     3
...
3     1
3     2
3     4
```

Something like `separate` or `strsplit` doesn't seem on it's own to be the solution. Separate fails with warnings that various columns have too many values (NB id 3 has more values than id 1).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(data, treatments)

#   id treatments
#1   1          1
#2   1          2
#3   1          3
#4   2          2
#5   2          3
#6   3          8
#7   3          9
#8   3          1
#9   3          2
#10  3          4
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for this @Psidom

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
data  %>% 
  separate(treatments, paste0("v", 1:5)) %>% 
  gather(var, treatments, -id) %>% 
  na.exclude %>% 
  select(id, treatments) %>%
  arrange(id)


   id treatments
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   1          3
4   2          2
5   2          3
6   3          8
7   3          9
8   3          1
9   3          2
10  3          4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(treatments = stringr::str_split(treatments, ",")) %>% 
  unnest()

   id treatments
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   1          3
4   2          2
5   2          3
6   3          8
7   3          9
8   3          1
9   3          2
10  3          4
```