# r split a column into multiple columns

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to split a column of strings in a dataframe into multiple columns based a delimiting pattern, i.e., a column of strings "a b" and "c  d" should be split into two columns, one with "a" and "c", and another with "b" and "d". The delimiting pattern is in my case any sequence of characters that does not contain `a-zA-Z0-9@.`

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns) I'm trying to use `stringr`. However, it seems that `str_split` is sensitive to the number of spaces?

```
> xxx<-str_split_fixed(c("a b", "c  d")," ",3)
> xxx
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "a"  "b"  ""  
 [2,] "c"  ""   "d" 

> xxx<-str_split_fixed(c("a b", "c  d"),"[:space:] ",3)
> xxx
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] ""   "b"  ""  
 [2,] ""   " d" ""  

> xxx<-str_split_fixed(c("a b", "c  d"),"' '+",3)
> xxx
      [,1]   [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "a b"  ""   ""  
 [2,] "c  d" ""   ""
```

Comment: Try `tidyr::separate` as a nice shortcut. Also please specify the pattern in your question (there are unfinished sentences). If you want example code, you should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Gregor sorry for the unfinished sentences, I've hit enter too rapidly.

Comment: `str_split_fixed(c("a b", "c  d"),"\\s+",2)` but I m confused as to why you specify 3 instead of 2 columns

Comment: @Sotos 3 because in the real example there may be 3... Thank you very much!

Comment: ok. So by using the regex `\\s+` for the pattern, you can adjust `n` accordingly and you should be good to go