# Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character

Tags: r

When running the below code getting the error

```
weather <- as.tibble(fread("../input/weather-data-in-new-york-city-2016/weather_data_nyc_centralpark_2016.csv"))

> weather <- weather %>%>
+   mutate(date = dmy(date),
+          rain = as.numeric(ifelse(precipitation == "T", "0.01", precipitation)),
+          s_fall = as.numeric(ifelse(`snow fall` == "T", "0.01", `snow fall`)),
+          s_depth = as.numeric(ifelse(`snow depth` == "T", "0.01", `snow depth`)),
+          all_precip = s_fall + rain,
+          has_snow = (s_fall > 0) | (s_depth > 0),
+          has_rain = rain > 0,
+          max_temp = `maximum temerature`,
+          min_temp = `minimum temperature`)

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'.
```

below are the details of the data table.

```
> str(weather)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   366 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ date,maximum temerature,minimum temperature,average temperature,precipitation,snow fall,snow depth: chr  "1-1-2016,42,34,38.0,0.00,0.0,0" "2-1-2016,40,32,36.0,0.00,0.0,0" "3-1-2016,45,35,40.0,0.00,0.0,0" "4-1-2016,36,14,25.0,0.00,0.0,0" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in mutate\_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: unused argument (label = TRUE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702747/error-in-mutate-impl-data-dots-evaluation-error-unused-argument-label-t)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe your table doesn't actually have a column named "date".

Answer (score 0):

From the details you posted in `str(weather)`, it currently has every column collapsed together into one character class column, named `date,maximum temerature,minimum temperature,average temperature,precipitation,snow fall,snow depth`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns) discusses various methods for splitting a dataframe. I'm using `separate` from hadley's `tidyr` package to manipulate your dataset here, but you can try out the rest as well:

```
# reproducible dataset based on OP's data frame details
weather <- data.frame(`date,maximum temerature,minimum temperature,average temperature,precipitation,snow fall,snow depth` = 
                           c("1-1-2016,42,34,38.0,0.00,0.0,0",
                             "2-1-2016,40,32,36.0,0.00,0.0,0",
                             "3-1-2016,45,35,40.0,0.00,0.0,0",
                             "4-1-2016,36,14,25.0,0.00,0.0,0"),
                      stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = FALSE)

library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

new.column.names <- colnames(weather)[1] %>% strsplit(",") %>% unlist()
colnames(weather)[1] <- "single.column" # rename the column, because that column name is just asking for typos

weather <- weather %>%
  separate(col = single.column, 
           into = new.column.names, 
           sep = ",")
```