# Split a column of a table to multiple columns given the input of separators

Tags: r, regex

Maybe what I want to do it's impossible, so I made this question to know if there is a way or not. 
After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns) here in stackoverflow I saw that there is a way to split a column in different columns, but it's not what I wanted, I have an app in shiny where I can have tables with values like:

```
Phones                             price
Nokia 1234D - J298 6732 - LM 2       103$
Samsung 3342L - J2YY 4372 - YU 3     130$
Samsung 3042X - IKAA 3221 - GN 4    102$
```

So the user comes and says I want to divide those values in column **Phones** as I want, so the idea that came to my mind was to make the user write something like (" ", " - ", "  ", " - ") because I mean separate *nokia, 1234D, J298, 6732, LM 2* in 5 columns given the mentioned separators.

Here is the example code:

```
library(stringr)
c=c(" "," - "," "," - ")
mytable <-data.table(Phones=c("Nokia 1234D - J298 6732 - LM 2",      
                                      "Samsung 3342L - J2YY 4372 - YU 3",
                                      "Samsung 3042X - IKAA 3221 - GN 4"),price= c("103$", "130$", "102$") )
 aux = str_split_fixed(mytable$Phones, c, 5)
  mytable<-data.table( aux, mytable$price)
```

But I get the following result which is not what I want it separates as it wants , duplicates the first row.:

```
              V1        V2   V3   V4          V5   V2
1:         Nokia     1234D    - J298 6732 - LM 2 103$
2: Samsung 3342L J2YY 4372 YU 3                  130$
3:       Samsung     3042X    - IKAA 3221 - GN 4 102$
4:   Nokia 1234D J298 6732 LM 2                  103$
```

If you have a better solution it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `separate` the 'Phones' column into 5 columns with `extra= "merge"` to keep the last column with strings `"LM 2", "YU 3"` etc

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mytable %>% 
  separate(Phones, into = paste0("V", 1:5), remove = FALSE, extra = "merge")
#                             Phones      V1    V2   V3   V4   V5 price
#1:   Nokia 1234D - J298 6732 - LM 2   Nokia 1234D J298 6732 LM 2  103$
#2: Samsung 3342L - J2YY 4372 - YU 3 Samsung 3342L J2YY 4372 YU 3  130$
#3: Samsung 3042X - IKAA 3221 - GN 4 Samsung 3042X IKAA 3221 GN 4  102$
```

If we need a custom split, then use `extract`

```
mytable %>%
   extract(Phones, into = paste0("V", 1:4), remove = FALSE, 
     "^(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+\\s+\\w+)")
#                             Phones            V1   V2   V3   V4 price
#1:   Nokia 1234D - J298 6732 - LM 2   Nokia 1234D J298 6732 LM 2  103$
#2: Samsung 3342L - J2YY 4372 - YU 3 Samsung 3342L J2YY 4372 YU 3  130$
#3: Samsung 3042X - IKAA 3221 - GN 4 Samsung 3042X IKAA 3221 GN 4  102$
```

The `^` implies the start of the string followed by word (`\\w+`) followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and the next word (`\\w+`) which we capture as a group (`(...)`) similarly the characters are matched based on the word, space characters

NOTE: The first approach gives the expected output as described in the post and the second one from the one requested in the comments

---

If we need to split by the custom splits in "c"

```
library(stringr)
c <- c(" "," - "," "," - ") #it is better to avoid function names for object names
fsplit <- function(str1, splt) {
       lst <- str_split(str1, splt, n = 2)
       v1 <- sapply(lst, `[`, 1)
       v2 <- sapply(lst, `[`, 2)
       list(v1, v2)
    }  

mytable[, V5 := Phones]
nm1 <- paste0("V", seq_along(c))
for(i in seq_along(c)){
  tmp <- fsplit(mytable$V5, c[i])
  mytable[, (nm1[i]) := tmp[[1]]]
  mytable[, V5 := tmp[[2]]][]
}
setcolorder(mytable,  c("Phones", nm1, "V5", "price"))
mytable
#                             Phones      V1    V2   V3   V4   V5 price
#1:   Nokia 1234D - J298 6732 - LM 2   Nokia 1234D J298 6732 LM 2  103$
#2: Samsung 3342L - J2YY 4372 - YU 3 Samsung 3342L J2YY 4372 YU 3  130$
#3: Samsung 3042X - IKAA 3221 - GN 4 Samsung 3042X IKAA 3221 GN 4  102$
```

Comment: This works but what if the user want to keep `Nokia 1234D` together ?

Comment: @David Arenburg thanks for comment that is exactly what I wanted to say!!

Comment: @ProgrammerMan  Then you may need `extract` i.e. `mytable %>% extract(Phones, into = paste0("V", 1:4), remove = FALSE, "^(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)")`

Comment: Thanks @akrun but can you explain what is exactly doing this code `^(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)` and in column V4 it should be LM 2 ... it deleted the numbers.

Comment: @ProgrammerMan  If you want the numbers, I can keep it.  I thought you want only up til LM

Comment: @ProgrammerMan  I updated with the custom splits.  Sorry, I thought to go for the easy way instead of custom splits

Comment: Thank you!! that works for different given inputs! @akrun

Comment: @DavidArenburg, zx8754, sorry guys, I didn't read the custom split part.  corrected