# Split a data frame column containing multiple phone numbers

Tags: r

For example one of the row contains 9343435445/9433445532. I would like to split these and paste individual ones separately in a new column.
I tried the following.

```
bookings <- read.csv(file = 'bookings.csv', header = T)
bookings$set1 <- as.character(bookings$set1)
bookings$set3 <- gsub('\\/..........', '',bookings$set1)
bookings$set4 <- gsub('\\d{10}\\/', ' ',bookings$set1)
```

But is not giving the desired output.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/4350440/4137985

Comment: Can you give a better (larger) example of your input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strcapture` from base r (`R` ≥ 3.4.0)

```
strcapture("(\\d+)/(\\d+)","9343435445/9433445532",data.frame(A=numeric(),B=numeric()))
           A          B
1 9343435445 9433445532
```

Comment: I had no idea about `strcapture`. Seems very useful!

Comment: Yeah it is. Sometimes I find it hard to learn new packages due to the base functions

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

So something like this:
`separate(data = data, col = phonenumber, into = c("phonenumber1", "phonenumber2", sep = "/"))`