# strsplit and keep part before first underscore

Tags: r, string, split

I would like to keep the part after the FIRST undescore. Please see example code.

```
colnames(df)
"EGAR00001341740_P32_1"    "EGAR00001341741_PN32"
```

My try, but does not give `P32_1` but only `P32` which is wrong.

```
sapply(strsplit(colnames(df), split='_', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
```

desired output: `P32_1, PN32`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be done with a regex by matching zero or more characters that are not an underscore (`[^_]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by an underscore (`_`) and replace it with blanks (`""`)

```
colnames(df) <- sub("^[^_]*_", "", colnames(df))
colnames(df)
#[1] "P32_1" "PN32"
```

---

With `strsplit`, it will split whereever the `split` character occurs.  One option is `str_split` from `stringr` where there is an option to specify the 'n' i.e. number of split parts.  If we choose `n = 2`, we get 2 substrings as it will only split at the first `_`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_split(colnames(df), "_",  n = 2), `[`, 2)
#[1] "P32_1" "PN32"
```

Comment: If we want to split at 3rd underscore is there a way to do that? Eg: `TCGA_3C_AAAU_01`, separate TCGA_3C_AAAU and 01 into 2 columns

Comment: @user5249203 try with `strsplit(sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_", "\\1,", v1), ",")`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ways. The first fixes the code in the question and the remaining ones are alternatives.  All use only base except (6).  (4) and (7) assume that the first field is fixed length, which is the case in the question.

```
x <- c("EGAR00001341740_P32_1", "EGAR00001341741_PN32")

# 1 - using strsplit
sapply(strsplit(x, "_"), function(x) paste(x[-1], collapse = "-"))
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32"

# 2 - a bit easier using sub.  *? is a non-greedy match
sub(".*?_", "", x)
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32" 

# 3 - locate the first underscore and extract all after that
substring(x, regexpr("_", x) + 1)
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32" 

# 4 - if the first field is fixed length as in the example
substring(x, 17)
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32" 

# 5 - replace first _ with character that does not appear and remove all until it
sub(".*;", "", sub("_", ";", x))
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32" 

# 6 - extract everything after first _
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "_(.*)", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32" 

# 7 - like (4) assumes fixed length first field
read.fwf(textConnection(x), widths = c(16, 99), as.is = TRUE)$V2
## [1] "P32_1" "PN32"
```