# How to find non- match or a inverse str_extract_all to construct a dataframe with non matches values in R

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, tidyverse, stringr

my question is:

If i have the next df:

```
df<- data.frame(Respuestas=c("sí, acepto, a veces, no acepto",
                            "no acepto, sí, acepto, a veces, nunca",
                            "a veces, sí, acepto, nunca, bla bla"))
print(df)

                             Respuestas
1        sí, acepto, a veces, no acepto
2 no acepto, sí, acepto, a veces, nunca
3   a veces, sí, acepto, nunca, bla bla
```

So I needed to extract by columns all string they matched "`Respuestas`" column with a dictionary, so I applied the @divibisan solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102092/r-extract-the-matched-string-split-into-multiple-columns-which-are-matched-by). So far, all very good, I get my output

```
vec<-c("sí, acepto", "a veces", "no acepto")

t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                          str_extract_all(x[['Respuestas']], vec, simplify = TRUE)))

[,1]         [,2]      [,3]       
[1,] "sí, acepto" "a veces" "no acepto"
[2,] "sí, acepto" "a veces" "no acepto"
[3,] "sí, acepto" "a veces" ""
```

But, finally I want to get a data frame with the non-match values between **"Respuestas"** *column* string and the **vec** dictionary, something like this:

```
wishDF<- data.frame(noMatch1=c(NA,
                    "nunca",
                    "nunca"),
                    noMatch2= c(NA,NA, "bla bla"))
print(wishDF)

    noMatch1 noMatch2
1     <NA>     <NA>
2    nunca     <NA>
3    nunca  bla bla
```

I was trying to use `str_detect` and `invert_match` from `stringr` library in the same way that @divibisan solution, but I dont get good result. What do you recommend me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the content of a string that doesn't match is simply to remove the content that does match:

```
str_remove(string, pattern)
```

But this function is vectorized on `pattern`, so it will remove only one entry from `vec` each time. We need to go to the implementation: `str_remove` is an alias for `str_replace(string, pattern, "")` which is based on the `stringi` package. So we can do this with:

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_coll(string, pattern, "", vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Finally we want to do that for every row in Respuetas, we can do that simply with `map`:

```
map_chr(df$Respuestas,
    ~ stringi::stri_replace_all_coll(.x, vec, "", vectorize_all = FALSE))
# [1] ", , "               ", , , nunca"        ", , nunca, bla bla"
```

With regards to `noMatch1` and `noMatch2`, it is possible to separate the result based on ",". But I don't know enough about your data to be sure it'll work: do you always have the same number of fields? How do you distinguish between the comma in "si, acepto" and the one between "si, acepto" and "nunca"?

Depending on your data, something like this may or may not work (and may or may not make any sense at all):

```
df %>%
  mutate(no_match = map_chr(Respuestas,
                            ~ stringi::stri_replace_all_coll(.x, vec, "", vectorize_all = FALSE))) %>%
  separate(col = no_match,
           into = c("first", "second", "third", "fourth"),
           sep = ",",
           extra = "merge",
           fill = "left")
```