# Splitting a column into multiple columns in R, when there is no "separator"

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame with eight digit numbers, each corresponding to one

```
x <- data.frame(y = c(12345678, 87654321))
```

I want 8 columns such that each column corresponds to one number i.e.

```
   y1   y2   y3   y4   y5   y6   y7   y8
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     
    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

(The columns don't have to be named y1 to y8, I'm just naming them that way for illustrative purposes)

Normally in R, I would use `separate`, but here there is no clear separator. How can I do this?

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate but it is different.  The so-called duplicate had separators but this one does not.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  `""` is the separator here. There are at least 2 solution from that link which fits as an answer here and gives the expected output.

Comment: `str_split_fixed(x$y, "", 8);`
`do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(x$y),''));`
`do.call(rbind, str_split(x$y, ''))`
`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns

Comment: This one is specifically mentions a preference for separate and that one does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`separate` can accept column positions in the `sep` argument.  This acts as if there were separators after columns 1, 2, ..., 7.

```
library(tidyr)

separate(x, y, into = paste0("y", 1:8), sep = 1:7)
```

giving:

```
  y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit`

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(x, 1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "")))))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
#1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
#2  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Or a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    mutate(y = strsplit(as.character(y), "")) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    mutate(var = paste0("y", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(var, y) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-row)
#  y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6    y7    y8
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
#2 8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another R base alternative

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x$y), "")))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from `stringr`

```
data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(x$y, "", 8))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```