# Height conversion in R

Tags: r

I have recently started learning R and I am facing an issue.
I have a column in my data which have height of players in (feet'inches) format.
I want to create a new column for height in centimeters. For this I used the "strsplit" function as below(df is the height column):

```
l <- strsplit(df,"'",fixed = T)
print(l)
```

```
[[1]]

[1] "5" "7"

[[2]]

[1] "6" "2"

[[3]]

[1] "5" "9"

[[4]]

[1] "6" "4"

[[5]]

[1] "5"  "11"

[[6]]

[1] "5" "8"
```

I am getting stuck here as I don't know how to obtain the required value after splitting the field.

I am trying to use the below code but its giving the following error:

```
p_pos <- grep("'",df)
l[[p_pos]][1]
```

`Error in l[[p_pos]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2`

I am expecting the above code to print the values from the first column in the list

`5 6 5 6 5 5`

```
>dput(head(df, 10))
c("5'7", "6'2", "5'9", "6'4", "5'11", "5'8")
```

Comment: please share data with `dput(head(df, 10))` (paste the result in your post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a vector with the heights in centimeters.

We are applying to your whole list a function that turns the number string into numeric and multiplies it with the conversion to cm.

```
l = list()
l[[1]] = c("5","7")
l[[2]] = c("6","2")
l[[3]] = c("5","9")
l[[4]] = c("6","4")
l[[5]] = c("5","11")
l[[6]] = c("5","8")

sapply(l,function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)*c(30.48,2.54)))
[1] 170.18 187.96 175.26 193.04 180.34 172.72
```

Comment: Thanks! I have many rows present in my actual column. Can you please show how I can do the assigning part(l[[1]] = c("5","7")) for all of them using a loop. Thanks again.

Comment: I did the part just to get the same list you were printing. I imagine that `l <- strsplit(df,"'",fixed = T)` should return the values for all rows this same way.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to create a data frame with a column of feet and a column of inches.  The `separate` function in the `tidyr` package handles this well - see [this answer by its creator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168383/1556369).

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df = data.frame(height = c("5'7", "6'2", "5'9", "6'4", "5'11", "5'8"))
> df %>% separate(height, c('feet', 'inches'), "'", convert = TRUE) %>% 
+     mutate(cm = (12*feet + inches)*2.54)
  feet inches     cm
1    5      7 170.18
2    6      2 187.96
3    5      9 175.26
4    6      4 193.04
5    5     11 180.34
6    5      8 172.72
```

The `separate` creates a data frame with columns of feet and inches; the `mutate` does the conversion to centimeters.