# Is there any option to do Column split?

Tags: r

Need to see maker names against car models

something like this:
[image]

trying to use below function, but it is creating as list

```
strsplit(carz$maker,split = " ")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `lapply()` with the Motor Trend Cars data frame.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$type <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$make <-unlist(lapply(strsplit(mtcars$type," "),function(x){x[[1]]}))
head(mtcars)
```

and the result:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
                               type    make
Mazda RX4                 Mazda RX4   Mazda
Mazda RX4 Wag         Mazda RX4 Wag   Mazda
Datsun 710               Datsun 710  Datsun
Hornet 4 Drive       Hornet 4 Drive  Hornet
Hornet Sportabout Hornet Sportabout  Hornet
Valiant                     Valiant Valiant
>
```

Note, that some additional data cleaning is necessary, because the Valiant and Duster were made by Plymouth, the Camaro Z28 was made by Chevrolet, and the Hornet 4 Drive was made by American Motor Cars, also known as AMC.

Regarding the question in the comments about the syntax used within `lapply()`, I used `lapply()` to process the results of `strsplit()`, including an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions) that extracts the first word from each element of the list.

Since the output of an R function can be used as the argument to another function, this solution nests functions to produce the desired result.

The `sapply()` answer provided by akrun does the same thing, using output from `strsplit()` as its input, and using `[`, one of the four forms of the extract operator to extract the data. `sapply()` also produces a vector rather than a list as its output.

Comment: Thanks it really worked for me, however if you can explain about function(x){x[[1]]}) it would be helpful for me.

Comment: @varunBollam - sure, it does exactly the same thing as @akrun use of `sapply()`, as we posted our answers at about the same time. R supports a programming construct called anonymous functions, one of the basic building blocks of functional programming.  They can also use within the `apply()` familiy of functions.  I'll update my answer to provide additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

And of course, there's a `tidyverse` solution too; this is what the `separate` function was designed for.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("type") %>% 
  separate(type, c("make", "model"), 
           extra="merge", fill="right", remove=FALSE)
```

Showing a selection of the output:

```
                  type     make       model
1            Mazda RX4    Mazda         RX4
2        Mazda RX4 Wag    Mazda     RX4 Wag
3           Datsun 710   Datsun         710
4       Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet     4 Drive
5    Hornet Sportabout   Hornet  Sportabout
6              Valiant  Valiant        <NA>
7           Duster 360   Duster         360
8            Merc 240D     Merc        240D
9             Merc 230     Merc         230
10            Merc 280     Merc         280
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strsplit` retuns a `list`, we need to loop through the `list` and extract the first word to get a vector

```
carz$maker <- sapply(strsplit(carz$maker,split = " "), `[`, 1)
```

Reproducible with `mtcars`

```
sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), `[`, 1)
#[1] "Mazda"    "Mazda"    "Datsun"   "Hornet"   "Hornet"   "Valiant"  "Duster"   "Merc"     "Merc"     "Merc"     "Merc"    
#[12] "Merc"     "Merc"     "Merc"     "Cadillac" "Lincoln"  "Chrysler" "Fiat"     "Honda"    "Toyota"   "Toyota"   "Dodge"   
#[23] "AMC"      "Camaro"   "Pontiac"  "Fiat"     "Porsche"  "Lotus"    "Ford"     "Ferrari"  "Maserati" "Volvo"
```

---

It can also be done without `strsplit`

```
carz$maker <- sub("\\s+.*", row.names(carz))
```

Or with `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(carz$maker, 1)
```