# How to Split Text Within DataFrame

Tags: r, nlp

Can you help me delimit the data in column 1(rawtext) to

column 2(name),
column 3(timestamp),
column 4(speech_text)?

The data looks like this:

```
    column 1                                                         column 2
[1] firstname Lastname:           00:01     text text. text.          0
[2] firstname lastname2:          00:008    text, text text.          0
```

I need it to look like

```
column1                     column 2      colum3

[1] Firstname lastname      00:01         text text. text.
[2] firstname lastname2     00:08         text, text text.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP has a data.frame of which the first column should be splitted into three separate columns. The columns are separated by 4 or more white space characters.

The `data.table` package has the `tstrsplit()` function which is an abbreviation of  `transpose(strsplit(...))`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("name", "timestamp", "speech_text") := tstrsplit(column1, "\\s{4,}")]
df
```

> ```
>                                                     column1 column2                 name timestamp      speech_text
> 1: firstname Lastname:           00:01     text text. text.       0  firstname Lastname:     00:01 text text. text.
> 2: firstname lastname2:          00:008    text, text text.       0 firstname lastname2:    00:008 text, text text.
> ```

Note that the new columns have been appended to the original data.frame `df` *in place*.

Also note that `tstrsplit()` has coerced `column1` from factor to character by default.

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  column1 = c("firstname Lastname:           00:01     text text. text.", 
              "firstname lastname2:          00:008    text, text text."),
  column2 = 0)
df
```

> ```
>                                                    column1 column2
> 1 firstname Lastname:           00:01     text text. text.       0
> 2 firstname lastname2:          00:008    text, text text.       0
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use strsplit and regex to find more than 3 spaces toghether.

```
#Replication of the dataframe
l1 = "firstname Lastname:           00:01     text text. text.          0"
l2 = "firstname lastname2:          00:008    text, text text.          0"
df = rbind(l1,l2)

# Using strsplit with Regex to find separation with 3 or more spaces.

df2=as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(df,"\\s{3,}")),nrow = nrow(df), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Strplit generates a list, so it's necessary to unlist and use a matrix to recreate a data frame.

The output is:

```
+----------------------+--------+------------------+----+
|          V1          |   V2   |        V3        | V4 |
+----------------------+--------+------------------+----+
| firstname Lastname:  | 00:01  | text text. text. |  0 |
| firstname lastname2: | 00:008 | text, text text. |  0 |
+----------------------+--------+------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I received this error: 

Error in strsplit(df, "\\s{3,}") : non-character argument

Comment: In my example df is a character. It seems like in your example df is a dataframe, so in strsplit you need to indicate which column are you taking, for example, **strplit(df$V1,"\\s{3,}")**