# How do I calculate semi-colon separated values within a cell?

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
> head(dt)
               variant_id           transcript_id        HH     HNL  NLNL
1: chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 32968;685 1440;20 337;1
2: chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1
3: chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1
4: chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1
5: chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1
6: chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1
```

What I would like to do is take values in column `HH` and divide the numbers before the semi-colon by the numbers after the semi-colon. For example, for the first row, I would like to do `32968/685` (which would be `48.13`). Then, I would like to do the same for the values in column `NLNL` (so for the first row that would be `337`), and then I would like to subtract the value found from column `HH` from the value in column `NLNL`, so `337-48.13 = 228.87`. I would then like to take that value in place it into a new column called `diff` for all rows.

How would I go about doing this? I can pretty easily figure out how to divide the values of one column with another and put the result in a new column, but I don't know how to extract semi-colon separated values from within a cell and manipulate them.

Comment: Do none of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4350440/5325862) work for splitting your columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option. We split the data in a nested cell, then map out the values.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  mutate_at(vars(HH:NLNL), list(~str_split(., ";") )) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(HH:NLNL), list(~map_dbl(., ~as.numeric(.x) %>% {.[[1]]/.[[2]]}))) 

#>   variant_id             transcript_id              HH   HNL  NLNL
#>   <chr>                  <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  72     337
#> 2 chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#> 3 chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#> 4 chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#> 5 chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#> 6 chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
```

EDIT: All you have to do to have new variables is to name them in the list:

```
dt %>%
  mutate_at(vars(HH:NLNL), list(new = ~str_split(., ";") )) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(HH_new:NLNL_new), list(~map_dbl(., ~as.numeric(.x) %>% {.[[1]]/.[[2]]})))

#>   variant_id       transcript_id      HH     HNL   NLNL  HH_new HNL_new NLNL_new
#>   <chr>            <chr>              <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 chr10_60842447_… chr10_60871326_60… 32968… 1440… 337;1   48.1    72        337
#> 2 chr10_60846892_… chr10_60871326_60… 33157… 1251… 337;1   48.1    83.4      337
#> 3 chr10_60847284_… chr10_60871326_60… 33157… 1251… 337;1   48.1    83.4      337
#> 4 chr10_60849980_… chr10_60871326_60… 33157… 1251… 337;1   48.1    83.4      337
#> 5 chr10_60850566_… chr10_60871326_60… 33157… 1251… 337;1   48.1    83.4      337
#> 6 chr10_60852394_… chr10_60871326_60… 33157… 1251… 337;1   48.1    83.4      337
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can place these values in a new column?

Comment: This is great. Can you break it down a little bit for me? For example, what does the tilde do at `~str_split` and `~map_dbl` and `~as.numeric`? What about the dot before `.x` and `.[[1]]` etc? I'm guessing the dot as an argument references the first argument in `mutate_at`?

Comment: Correct. I'll probably use the incorrect vocabulary or explain it half correctly, but the `.` is a reference to the variable in `vars` or the result of the previous pipe (i.e., `%>%`). The `.x` is a reference in `map` to the `.` which is a reference to the variable in `var`. That sounds kind of confusing, but I recommend reading at little on the `dplyr` `*_at()` and `*_all()` functions, as well as the `purrr` `map_*()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `split` by `;` with `strsplit`, convert to `numeric` and divide the first element by the second

```
dt[, new := unlist(lapply(strsplit(HH, ";"), 
        function(x) as.numeric(x[1])/as.numeric(x[2])))]
```

Or another option is reading the column as a `data.table` with `fread` and then do the division

```
dt[, new := fread(text = .SD[["HH"]], sep=";")[, V1/V2]]
```

---

For multiple columns, specify the columns in `.SDcols`, loop over the columns and do the same thing

```
dt[, paste0("new", 1:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         fread(text = x, sep=";")[, V1/V2]), .SDcols = HH:NLNL]
dt
#               variant_id           transcript_id        HH     HNL  NLNL     new1 new2 new3
#1: chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 32968;685 1440;20 337;1 48.12847 72.0  337
#2: chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362 83.4  337
#3: chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362 83.4  337
#4: chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362 83.4  337
#5: chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362 83.4  337
#6: chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362 83.4  337
```

---

Or an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(HH, HNL, NLNL, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(rn, variant_id, transcript_id) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(HH:NLNL), ~ first(.)/last(.)) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  variant_id             transcript_id              HH   HNL  NLNL
#  <chr>                  <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  72     337
#2 chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#3 chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#4 chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#5 chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
#6 chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443  48.1  83.4   337
```

---

It can be also done in a compact way with

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)# v 0.8.99.9000
dt %>%
     mutate(across(HH:NLNL, ~ fread(text = ., sep=";") %>% 
                      reduce(`/`)))
#              variant_id           transcript_id       HH  HNL NLNL
#1 chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.12847 72.0  337
#2 chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.05362 83.4  337
#3 chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.05362 83.4  337
#4 chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.05362 83.4  337
#5 chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.05362 83.4  337
#6 chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.05362 83.4  337
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(variant_id = c("chr10_60842447_A_G_b38", 
      "chr10_60846892_G_A_b38", 
"chr10_60847284_C_T_b38", "chr10_60849980_T_C_b38", "chr10_60850566_A_T_b38", 
"chr10_60852394_C_A_b38"), transcript_id = c("chr10_60871326_60871443", 
"chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443", 
"chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443"), HH = c("32968;685", 
"33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690"
), HNL = c("1440;20", "1251;15", "1251;15", "1251;15", "1251;15", 
"1251;15"), NLNL = c("337;1", "337;1", "337;1", "337;1", "337;1", 
"337;1")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option involving `dplyr` and `gsubfn` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(HH, HNL, NLNL), ~ gsubfn("([0-9]+);([0-9]+)", function(x, y) as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y), .))

             variant_id           transcript_id               HH  HNL NLNL
1 chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.1284671532847   72  337
2 chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.0536231884058 83.4  337
3 chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.0536231884058 83.4  337
4 chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.0536231884058 83.4  337
5 chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.0536231884058 83.4  337
6 chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 48.0536231884058 83.4  33
```

Comment: Note that `function(x, y) as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y)` could be written as `~as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `strsplit` to deal with semicolon separated values in a cell:

```
df <- cbind(df,`colnames<-`(sapply(c("HH","HNL","NLNL"),
                             function(v) sapply(strsplit(df[,v],split = ";"),
                                                function(x) Reduce("/",as.numeric(x)))),c("HHnew","HNLnew","NLNLnew")))
df$diff <- with(df,NLNLnew - HHnew)
```

such that

```
> df
              variant_id           transcript_id        HH     HNL  NLNL    HHnew HNLnew NLNLnew     diff
1 chr10_60842447_A_G_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 32968;685 1440;20 337;1 48.12847   72.0     337 288.8715
2 chr10_60846892_G_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362   83.4     337 288.9464
3 chr10_60847284_C_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362   83.4     337 288.9464
4 chr10_60849980_T_C_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362   83.4     337 288.9464
5 chr10_60850566_A_T_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362   83.4     337 288.9464
6 chr10_60852394_C_A_b38 chr10_60871326_60871443 33157;690 1251;15 337;1 48.05362   83.4     337 288.9464
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(variant_id = c("chr10_60842447_A_G_b38", "chr10_60846892_G_A_b38", 
"chr10_60847284_C_T_b38", "chr10_60849980_T_C_b38", "chr10_60850566_A_T_b38", 
"chr10_60852394_C_A_b38"), transcript_id = c("chr10_60871326_60871443", 
"chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443", 
"chr10_60871326_60871443", "chr10_60871326_60871443"), HH = c("32968;685", 
"33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690", "33157;690"
), HNL = c("1440;20", "1251;15", "1251;15", "1251;15", "1251;15", 
"1251;15"), NLNL = c("337;1", "337;1", "337;1", "337;1", "337;1", 
"337;1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```