# How to use values of a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, date

I have a data like this;

```
t1<-structure(list(`12/2018` = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("12/31/2018", 
"3/11/2011"), class = "factor"), X. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "-", class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", 
"X.", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `3/2011` = structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("12/31/2018", 
    "3/11/2011"), class = "factor"), X. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "-", class = "factor"), 
        Value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", 
    "X.", "Value"), row.names = 14:26, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("12/2018", 
"3/2011"))
```

And I want to create a dataframe by considering `date` column for both 2 objects in the list like below;

```
df<-data.frame("Day" = , "Month" = , "Year" = )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collapse the list into a dataframe, you could use `rbind()`:

`` t2 <- rbind(t1$`12/2018`,t1$`3/2011`) ``

EDIT:
In the comments, OP mentioned that they want to do this for arbitrary columns.

For this, use `do.call()`. You may also want to remove the row names:

```
t2 <- do.call(t1,rbind)
rownames(t2) <- c()
```

There are other questions on Stack Overflow which explain how to split columns, so I linked one in the comments.

Comment: But I have many columns like 12/2018. And also I need a dataframe in format I wrote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns