# R separate string columns into two columns by position

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a question very similar to what discussed here: [Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns/4351918)
However, given the following dataframe:

```
before = data.frame(attr = c(1,30,4), Name=c('George','Mark','Susan'))
  attr          Name
1    1        George
2   30          Mark
3    4         Susan
```

I would need to split the "Name" column into multiples of 2 characters.
The expected result should be:

```
  attr          Split1     Split2    Split3
1    1            Ge         or        ge
2   30                       Ma        rk
3    4            S          us        an
```

I have honestly now idea of how use the dplyr separate feature to achieve that.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `extract` to capture groups with group position anchors at the end (`$`) of the string with two characters in the 2nd and 3rd group while the first can be flexible

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     extract(Name, into = str_c("Split", 1:3), "(.*?)(..)(..)$")
#   attr Split1 Split2 Split3
#1    1     Ge     or     ge
#2   30            Ma     rk
#3    4      S     us     an
```

---

or another option is to reverse the string and use the position as `sep` in `separate`

```
library(stringi)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Name = stri_reverse(Name)) %>% 
  separate(Name, into = str_c("Split", 3:1), sep=c(2, 4)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Split"), stri_reverse)) %>%
  select(attr, Split1:Split3)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(attr = c(1L, 30L, 4L), Name = c("George", "Mark", 
"Susan")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun , I get an error saying "across" doesn't exist even after importing those liibraries. Any suggestions? By the way, would it be easier, if I wanted to capture the first two most right letters of each string?

Comment: @Angelo I used `dplyr` 1.0.0 .  If your version is before that, `mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Split')), stri_reverse)`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an answer that maybe could help someone having the same problem I had. I was trying to separate a column by a specific position.

I found a `tidyr` function: `separate_wider_position`. The example given in the function documentation gave me what I wanted:

```
df <- tibble(id = 1:3, x = c("m-123", "f-455", "f-123"))
df %>% separate_wider_position(x, c(gender = 1, 1, unit = 3))
```

It separates the column `x` into `gender` and `unit` and removes the delimiter `"-"`. That example is given in the function documentation.

In my case, I didn't have a delimiter, but I wanted to separate using a specific position without removing any character:

```
df <- tibble(id = 1:3, x = c("m123", "f455", "f123"))
df %>% separate_wider_position(x, c(gender = 1, unit = 3))
```

This does the same separation without having a specific delimiter.

There are also some other similar functions: `separate_wider_delim` and `separate_wider_regex` that work for a specific delimiter or a regular expression. Those 3 share the same documentation.