# tidyr: separate column while retaining delimiter in the first column

Tags: r, tidyr, delimiter

I have a column that I am trying to break up into two while retaining the delimiter. I got this far, but part of the delimiter is being dropped. I also need to do this split a second time, adding the delimiter to the first column which I cannot figure out how to do.

```
duplicates <- data.frame(sample = c("a_1_b1", "a1_2_b1", "a1_c_1_b2"))

duplicates <- separate(duplicates, 
                       sample, 
                       into = c("strain", "sample"),
                       sep = "_(?=[:digit:])")
```

using only the first name as an example, my output is `a_1` and `b1` while my desired output is `a_1` and `_b1`.

I would also like to perform this split with the delimiter added to the first column as below.

| sample | batch |
| --- | --- |
| a_1_ | b1 |
| a1_2_ | b1 |
| a1_c_1_ | b2 |

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns) does not answer my question of how to retain the delimiter, or to control which side of the split it ends up on.

Comment: Although that dupe didn't answer it, there are 100s of questions that are asked with `separate` and I am sure that this was answered previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::extract` with capture groups.

```
tidyr::extract(duplicates, sample, c("strain", "sample"), '(.*_)(\\w+)')

#   strain sample
#1    a_1_     b1
#2   a1_2_     b1
#3 a1_c_1_     b2
```

The same regex can also be used with `strcapture` in base R -

```
strcapture('(.*_)(\\w+)', duplicates$sample, 
           proto = list(strain = character(), sample = character()))
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me. The second created an empty column called sample and assigned the entire string to strain. How would I edit this to achieve the opposite split (a_1 & _b1)?

Comment: The second solution seems to work similarly for me for the data that you have shared.

Comment: My actual data is formatted slightly differently so I am guessing that is why it isn't working. The second column isn't actually empty I realized. Using an actual column name not a simplified example I gave it is separating as `LEW_3_batch0` and `1` (this is batch 10) or `LEW_2_batch` and `8`

Comment: How can I adapt the first solution to give me the opposite split?

Comment: Like this? `tidyr::extract(duplicates, sample, c("strain", "sample"), '(.*?)(_.*)')`

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this is causing the split to be on the last _ in the string? I don't fully understand what is happening.

Comment: `.*` is greedy meaning it will match everything until last underscore. If you want to match till the first underscore use `?` i.e `(.*?)` as mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: In some cases their are 3 underscores and I still need to split on the second (last) but keeping the underscore attached to the second column like `a1_c_1 & _b2` how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

2. Update: see request of OP in comments:

```
duplicates %>% 
    mutate(batch = sub(".*_", "_", sample)) %>%  
    mutate(sample = sub("_[^_]+$", "", sample))
```

output:

```
  sample batch
1    a_1   _b1
2   a1_2   _b1
3 a1_c_1   _b2
```

**Update after clarification:** see comments:

```
duplicates %>% 
    mutate(batch = sub(".*_", "", sample)) %>%  
    mutate(sample = sub("_[^_]+$", "_", sample))
```

Output:

```
   sample batch
1    a_1_    b1
2   a1_2_    b1
3 a1_c_1_    b2
```

**First answer:**
We could use `str_sub` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

duplicates %>% 
    mutate(batch = str_sub(sample, -2,-1)) %>% 
    mutate(sample = str_sub(sample, end=-3))
```

Output:

```
   sample batch
1    a_1_    b1
2   a1_2_    b1
3 a1_c_1_    b2
```

Comment: what are the numbers indicating?

Comment: -2 = last two characters. -1 begin from end of string. -3 last three characters from string.

Comment: I should have provided a more accurate representation of the data. I sometimes have b10 values.

Comment: Please see my update. Now it should work more generally!

Comment: How would I edit this to receive the opposite switch (a_1 and _b1)? I am still a little iffy on how to use some of the R expressions.

Comment: I don't understand. What should be in sample and what in batch?

Comment: I need to perform the split in two different ways for two different analysis. Once I need `a_1_ & b1` and another time I need `a_1 & _b1`

Answer (score 2):

Using `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(duplicates, sample, into = c("strain", "sample"), 
        sep = "(?<=_)(?=[^_]+$)")
```

-output

```
    strain sample
1    a_1_     b1
2   a1_2_     b1
3 a1_c_1_     b2
```

---

For splitting the other way

```
separate(duplicates, sample, into = c("strain", "sample"), 
         sep = "(?<=[^_])(?=_[^_]+$)")
  strain sample
1    a_1    _b1
2   a1_2    _b1
3 a1_c_1    _b2
```