# How to use the method separate with a character?

Tags: r, tidyr

```
cerveceria_dataset$CLIENTE <- separate(cerveceria_dataset$CLIENTE, col = CLIENTE, into =  c("Nombre","Apellido"), sep = ";")
```

This code give me the

> "Error in UseMethod("separate") :
> no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character""[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntH6m.png)

Comment: You can't. It's intended for `data.frame`/1tibble` and the like. Could you provide your full data?

Comment: I linked the image in the description, its a .xls file loaded in r studio, so i must convert it into a data frame?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168383/6105259

Answer (score 1):

I think you are applying the function wrong. Try using -

```
cerveceria_dataset <- tidyr::separate(cerveceria_dataset, 
                       col = CLIENTE, into =  c("Nombre","Apellido"), sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`tidyr::separate`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) splits a string column into multiple columns. If you are just working with a single character vector, you probably want something like [`stringr::split`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html), which splits a character *vector* into a list of vectors (or a matrix if you use `str_split_fixed`).

Comment: i tried to do: "
cerveceria_dataset$CLIENTE <- split(cerveceria_dataset$CLIENTE, c("Nombre","Apellido"), ";")
"
b

Comment: but it just separate the data in the same colum, i want to get two colums by the colum CLIENTE

Comment: xD but i mean, i want splits a string column into multiple columns, i dont understand why when i use separate give me this error