# Split data frame string column into multiple columns (comma separated characters)

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, tidyr

I am trying to split a column of comma separated characters into several columns (as many as different characters overall).
I read similar questions such as this:

[Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

But the solutions were based on a small number of possible characters, so that the new columns could be named in advanced before the columns was split.

This is my example:

```
subject <- c(1,2,3)
 letters <- c("a, b, f, g", "b, g, m, l", "g, m, z")

df1 <- data.frame(subject, letters)

df1

 subject    letters
1       1 a, b, f, g
2       2 b, g, m, l
3       3    g, m, z
```

The desired result would be:

```
  subject a b f g m z
1       1 1 1 1 1 0 0
2       2 0 1 0 1 1 0
3       3 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using `str_split`, `unnest_longer` and `table`

```r
subject <- c(1,2,3)
letters <- c("a, b, f, g", "b, g, m, l", "g, m, z")

df1 <- data.frame(subject, letters)


library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(letters = str_split(letters, ', ')) %>%
  unnest_longer(letters) %>%
  table
#>        letters
#> subject a b f g l m z
#>       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#>       2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
#>       3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Seeing some of the other answers, `separate_rows` is a better solution here

```r
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(letters) %>%
  table
```

Answer (score 2):

A **base R** approach that `grepl`s the `unique` list of letters against each row of `trimws` and `strsplit`ed letters. Has the advantage of being able to easily interact with each step manually in case any adjustment needs to be done, e.g. order changes or leaving out letters etc.

```
list_letter <- sapply(strsplit(df1$letters, ","), trimws)
letter <- unique(unlist(list_letter))
letter
[1] "a" "b" "f" "g" "m" "l" "z"

data.frame( subject=df1$subject, 
            sapply(letter, function(x) sapply(list_letter, function(y) 
              any(grepl(x, y))))*1 )
  subject a b f g m l z
1       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
2       2 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
3       3 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse` possibility:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(letters) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = letters, values_fill = 0)

  subject     a     b     f     g     m     l     z
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2       2     0     1     0     1     1     1     0
3       3     0     0     0     1     1     0     1
```

Comment: Nice answer. You could use `values_fill = 0 ` in `pivot_wider` to spare the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(letters, sep = ', ') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = letters, values_from = letters, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  subject     a     b     f     g     m     l     z
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2       2     0     1     0     1     1     1     0
3       3     0     0     0     1     1     0     1
```