# Convert data. frame column character to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, bioinformatics, numeric

I am working on data frame which has information like this.

```
df<- as.data.frame(read.table("headen.bed",header = FALSE, sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote=""))
```

```
C1  C2    C3 
33  12249  0,300,3900,400,4500,400,4200
83  9213   0,49,66,75,158,160,170,183,218
146 680    0,3,13,129,274,278,383,481,482,496
```

I want to do addition of C1 into each element of C3, it would be something like.

```
C1  C2    C3 
33  12249  33,333,3933,433,4533,433,433
83  9213   83 132 149 158 241 243 253 266 301
146 680    146 149 159 275 420 424 529 627 628 642
```

but somehow its showing that the C3 is a character class, I tried. different ways to convert into numeric type using  `as.numeric`  `type.convert, character to factor and then numeric`
. But still didn't can anyone suggest best way to perform this?

Comment: the first element is only zero

Comment: can you please submit your data ?, the command dput comes handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, section "Copying original data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
mapply(function(x, y)paste(x + as.numeric(y), collapse = ','),df$C1 ,strsplit(df$C3, ','))
[1] "33,333,3933,433,4533,433,4233"  "83,132,149,158,241,243,253,266,301"  "146,149,159,275,420,424,529,627,628,642"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(C1 = c(33, 83, 146), 
                 C2 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 C3 = c('0,300,3900,400,4500,400,4200', '0,49,66,75,158,160,170,183,218', '0,3,13,129,274,278,383,481,482,496'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**EDIT**
To make `C3` into numeric you will have to split it into many columns. There are a bunch of ways to do it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns). I like the `splitstackshape` approach, i.e.

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1 <- cSplit(df, 'C3', sep = ',')

#C1 C2 C3_01 C3_02 C3_03 C3_04 C3_05 C3_06 C3_07 C3_08 C3_09 C3_10
#1:  33  1    33   333  3933   433  4533   433  4233    NA    NA    NA
#2:  83  2    83   132   149   158   241   243   253   266   301    NA
#3: 146  3   146   149   159   275   420   424   529   627   628   642

str(df1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ C1   : num  33 83 146
 $ C2   : num  1 2 3
 $ C3_01: int  33 83 146
 $ C3_02: int  333 132 149
 $ C3_03: int  3933 149 159
 $ C3_04: int  433 158 275
 $ C3_05: int  4533 241 420
 $ C3_06: int  433 243 424
 $ C3_07: int  4233 253 529
 $ C3_08: int  NA 266 627
 $ C3_09: int  NA 301 628
 $ C3_10: int  NA NA 642
```

Comment: It worked....but when i see the class of that data still its shows as character..can I convert into numeric. so that if required I can access each element..