# How to split each element in a string to a row in a new column?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have this dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(column = c("apple, banana, cherry",
"apple, banana, cherry, grape", 
"apple, banana, cherry, grape, pear")) 

data

  column
1 apple, banana, cherry
2 apple, banana, cherry, grape
3 apple, banana, cherry, grape, pear
```

I'd like my output to be:

```
  column1  column2  column3  column4  column5
1 apple    banana   cherry   NA       NA
2 apple    banana   cherry   grape    NA
3 apple    banana   cherry   grape    pear
```

I tried: `strsplit(data$column, ",")`, but this returns a list and I struggle to get it back into a dataframe type because the rows are of unequal length and this won't work: `as.data.frame(strsplit(data$column, ","))` .

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: I think it doesn't because the one you listed does not have an issue with unequal items in rows. The answer below by M.Viking is really good.

Comment: Hadleys second answer answers this, uneven rows doesn't matter since it will automatically pad them with NA. this is a a duplicate that's been asked about 100 times.

Comment: Fair enough, the 2nd answer indeed achieves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
separate(data=df, col=column, sep=", ", into=paste0("column_", 1:5))

  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4 column_5
1    apple   banana   cherry     <NA>     <NA>
2    apple   banana   cherry    grape     <NA>
3    apple   banana   cherry    grape     pear
```

You could automate the counting of the number of prospective columns with

```
library(stringr)
max(str_count(df$column, ","))+1 # returns 5
```