# Extract year, month and day when dates are non-standard format

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a column of dates, I want to extract the year, month and day into separate columns. Unfortunately there are inconsistent entries in the dates column, so the normal solution of using `format(as.Date(),"%Y")` or `lubridate::year()` doesn't work.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
dates_df <- data.frame(dates = c("1985-03-23", "", "1983", "1984-01"))
```

And here is the desired result:

```
       dates year month  day
1 1985-03-23 1985     3   23
2            <NA>  <NA> <NA>
3       1983 1983  <NA> <NA>
4    1984-01 1984     1 <NA>
```

I can achieve the desired result with the following code, but it is very slow on large datasets (>100,000 rows):

```
dates_df$year <- sapply(dates_df$dates, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\\-"))[1])
dates_df$month <- sapply(dates_df$dates, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\\-"))[2])
dates_df$day <- sapply(dates_df$dates, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\\-"))[3])
```

**My question:**

Is there a more efficient (fast) way to extract year, month, day columns from messy date data?

Comment: A few options here. If you really need speed maybe try the `data.table` option. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4350440

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense to think of it as a character splitting problem rather than a date problem.

Comment: Can you be sure in cases like `1984-01`, the `01` always denotes the month? Is there always a year?

Comment: would you ever have a scenario where you have year and day but not month

Comment: @jay.sf Yes 01 would always be month in your example.

Comment: @Mike, no, that scenario would not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strsplit` and adapting the `length`s.

```
cbind(dates_df, t(sapply(strsplit(dates_df$dates, '-'), `length<-`, 3)))
#        dates    1    2    3
# 1 1985-03-23 1985   03   23
# 2            <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 3       1983 1983 <NA> <NA>
# 4    1984-01 1984   01 <NA>
```

With nice names:

```
cbind(dates_df, `colnames<-`(
  t(sapply(strsplit(dates_df$dates, '-'), `length<-`, 3)), c('year', 'month', 'day')))
#        dates year month  day
# 1 1985-03-23 1985    03   23
# 2            <NA>  <NA> <NA>
# 3       1983 1983  <NA> <NA>
# 4    1984-01 1984    01 <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would have been to try `tidyr::separate`. Untested for speed and might break down if there are date formats not represented in the example data.

```
tidyr::separate(dates_df, 
                dates, 
                into = c('year', 'month', 'day'), 
                remove = FALSE)

#-----
       dates year month  day
1 1985-03-23 1985    03   23
2                  <NA> <NA>
3       1983 1983  <NA> <NA>
4    1984-01 1984    01 <NA>
```