# Which command is the most suitable to make one columns into two?

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), names = c("google analytics","amazon shop"))
```

Which command could create two columns using the space of names column?

Example output:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), names1 = c("google","amazon"), names2 = c("analytics","shop"))
```

Comment: `tidyr::separate` is a good option.

Comment: The answers to the purported duplicates are not ideal for this question.  I have re-opened it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns). No downvote, but I believe this is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: try `unglue::unglue_unnest(dframe, names, "{names1} {names2}")`

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is with `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
dframe %>%
  extract(names,
          into = c("names1", "names2"),
          regex = "(\\w+) (\\w+)")
  id names1    names2
1  1 google analytics
2  2 amazon      shop
```

Answer (score -2):

Here are some alternatives using the first instance of `dframe` given in the question.

**1) separate** Use `separate` as shown below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dframe %>% separate(names, into = c("names1", "names2"))
##  id names1    names2
## 1  1 google analytics
## 2  2 amazon      shop
```

**2) sub** or using base R only with `sub`

```
transform(dframe, names1 = sub(" .*", "", names),
                  names2 = sub(".* ", "", names),
                  names = NULL)
##   id names1    names2
## 1  1 google analytics
## 2  2 amazon      shop
```

**3) read.table** or using base R only with `read.table`

```
cbind(dframe[-2], 
      read.table(text = dframe[[2]], col.names = c("names1", "names2")))
##   id names1    names2
## 1  1 google analytics
## 2  2 amazon      shop
```

**3a)** Another way to use read.table is

```
tmp <- read.table(text = dframe$names)
transform(dframe, names1 = tmp[[1]], names2 = tmp[[2]], names = NULL)
```

**3b)** Yet another read.table approach is to paste together the fields in each row and then use read.table on that.

```
nms <- c("id", "names1", "names2")
read.table(text = with(dframe, paste(id, names)), col.names = nms)
##   id names1    names2
## 1  1 google analytics
## 2  2 amazon      shop
```

**4) sapply/strplit** Another base R solution can be obtained using `sapply` and `strsplit`.  We define a `field` function for convenience.

```
field <- function(x, i)  sapply(strsplit(x, " "), `[`, i)
transform(dframe, names1 = field(names, 1),
                  names2 = field(names, 2),
                  names = NULL)
##   id names1    names2
## 1  1 google analytics
## 2  2 amazon      shop
```